# ionic 2 app work perfectly on ionic serve but stuck on splashscreen on android emulator

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I am pretty new to ionic 2. I copied the folder from [this link](https://github.com/chsakell/ionic2-angular2-firebase) and followed all the steps as stated. It runs smoothly and no error on `ionic serve`, but when I run on android emulator, it just gets stuck on splash screen. It won't proceed to the log in page and I don't have any idea why. Any help would be appreciated please.

```
 Cordova CLI: 6.5.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1

OS: Windows 10

Node Version: v6.10.1
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? you could use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ and check logs...

Comment: @suraj yeah i did run on devtools. no error shown at all. thats the weirdest part that it run no problem in browser but could not load in android emulator and my android phone

Comment: Can't be sure.. Maybe plugins issue..  Try re-installing them correctly...

Comment: Can you put the code inside `config.xml` and `app.component.ts`?

Comment: Never mind i check the repo on github change `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>` in your `config.xml` and see what hapen?

Comment: @amin arghavani just plain white screen.